# CSS Help: div:hover~div does not work for div later in code

Tags: css, html, hover, opacity

[Example of page](http://mjiang.ca)

Sorry about the confusing title, I will try to describe the issue better here.

The page has two equal dividers, when I hover over the left div, I want the opacity to change as well, I want the opacity of the second div to change concurrently. The code currently does this, however, with the right divider, the hover only changes itself and not the left divider.

I am open to new ways to approach this as well.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="bgimage" id="left"> 
        <div class="text">
            <h1>Portfolio</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="bgimage" id="right"> 
        <div class="text">
            <h1>Photography</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrap {
    width:100%;
    height:100vh;
    background-color:#000;
}

.text {
    height:55px;
    opacity:0.9;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    position:absolute; 
    top:0; 
    bottom:0;
    margin:auto; width:50%;
}

.bgimage{
    width:50%;
    height:100vh;
    opacity: 0.6;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.8s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.8s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.8s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 0.8s ease-in-out;
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
}

#left {
    float:left;
    background-image:url(left.jpg);
}

#right {
    float: right;
    background-image:url(right.jpg);
}

#left:hover~div#right, #right:hover~div#left {
    opacity: 0.3;
}

#left:hover, #right:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course it will work for the first div but not the second, and you can never select a preceding element in CSS, your best shot is jQuery, take a look at this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.bgimage').hover(function () {
        $('.bgimage').removeClass('hovered').addClass('unhovered');
        $(this).addClass('hovered').removeClass('unhovered');
    });
});
```

Here's a **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Karim_AG/SQ5fF/)** of your example, I made minor CSS changes .. Hope it helps